# How do I make jQuery wait for an Ajax Call to finish before it returns

Tags: php, ajax

I have a weak server

When clients repeatedly request ajax service, the server stops working

Frequent demand ajax

My server is weakening

I want to make only one request. Upon completion he will be able to make another request

```
function checkItemd(item_id){
$("#checkBtn"+item_id).html("Processing..(Wait)").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-primary");
alert("One tool checked at a time - Click OK");
var payload_string = $("#payload_form").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajax-item-check",
    data:payload_string + "&itemId=" + item_id,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(result){
        if (result.result=="success"){
            if (result.works=="success"){
                var checkBtnMessage = result.response ? result.response : "'Sent to ' Email ";
                $("#checkBtn"+item_id).html(checkBtnMessage).removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success");
            }else{
                $("#checkBtn"+item_id).html("Error").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
                setTimeout('removeRow('+item_id+');',1000);
            }
        }else{
            $("#checkBtn"+item_id).html("Not available to sellers").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-warning");
        }
    
    }
});
return false;
```

---

Comment: If it always returns false, why do you need it to return after the ajax is finished?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485433/return-true-or-false-after-ajax-post-in-parent-function

Comment: What do I do please help me

What is the appropriate modification to this code?

Comment: Actually you need to handle it in your server. This is called `request throttling`. What technology you are using for `back-end`?

Comment: Look sir https://prnt.sc/t9s0j4 ,,,,About pressing chack Go and press again on Chack You can not Until the first thing ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop the user making multiple parallel requests, you can just set a flag which causes the function code not to be executable if the request is already in progress.

e.g. look at the `requestInProgress` flag in this example:

```
var requestInProgress = false;

function checkItemd(item_id) {
  if (requestInProgress == true) return false;

  $("#checkBtn"+item_id).html("Processing..(Wait)").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-primary");
  alert("One tool checked at a time - Click OK");
  var payload_string = $("#payload_form").serialize();
  requestInProgress = true;

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajax-item-check",
    data:payload_string + "&itemId=" + item_id,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(result){
        requestInProgress = false;

        if (result.result=="success") {
            if (result.works=="success") {
                var checkBtnMessage = result.response ? result.response : "'Sent to ' Email ";
                $("#checkBtn"+item_id).html(checkBtnMessage).removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success");
            }else{
                $("#checkBtn"+item_id).html("Error").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
                setTimeout('removeRow('+item_id+');',1000);
            }
        }else{
            $("#checkBtn"+item_id).html("Not available to sellers").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-warning");
        }
    
    }
  });
}
```

N.B. you might want to add an "error" callback so you can set the flag false again in the event of any kind of unexpected problem with the request. Otherwise the user would have to refresh the page before they could make the request again.

Comment: Dear I do not understand much in programming

How do I put numbers

where do I put it